Firefox started by Selenium WebDriver does not render videos
I use a ruby script to start Firefox using Selenium/GeckoDriver on Ubuntu 20.04.
When I start Firefox in such way, it doesn't play videos, an error in console says: <filename> could not be decoded.
But when I start the same Firefox manually from desktop, the same videos on the same web-pages work well.
I thought that Selenium creates another Firefox profile without some needed settings, but I've opened about:profiles page in both modes (run by Selenium and run manually) and the active profile points to the same folder.
What else can be the reason?

Finally, solved this issue with:

Installing the most recent geckodriver v0.34: https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/testing/geckodriver/Support.html

Firefox installed by snap: sudo snap install firefox (do not forget to remove apt version first: sudo apt-get remove -y firefox)

Adding this argument while running Firefox: --profile-root=/home/user/tmp


